# Caesar cipher only gets first value right

Tags: javascript, encryption, fromcharcode

My caesar cipher only works for the first letter, I've tried moving variables around, using a nested for loop, and just cant seem to figure it out.  `FREE PIZZA` should translate to `SERR CVMMN`, but it gives me a bunch of weird symbols, and lowercase translations.

```
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
let x = str;
let y = [];
let n = ''
for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    y.push(x.charCodeAt(i) + 13)

    console.log(x.charCodeAt(i))

}
console.log(y)

for(let j = 0; j < y.length; j++){
  console.log(y[j])
 n += String.fromCharCode(y[j])
}
console.log(n)

  return n;
}
```

Comment: charCode isn't doing what you want it to - it's not just letters in the alphabet.  I might just make an array that contains each letter of the alphabet.

Comment: @IrkenInvader  So you're saying that charCodeAt()+ 13, is returning symbols for the higher letters (e.g. why F translates well, while R gives me a -)?

Comment: yeah, there is a list here https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes so you can see how the math doesn't work out

Comment: `String.fromCharCode((c.charCodeAt() - 65 + 13) % 26 + 65)` worked for me when testing with a single capital letter variable, `c`. Might be helpful.

Comment: As long as I understand what I'm doing with the charCodeAt, and fromCharCode functions, I'm good.  I hate how these exercises assume I know the math.

Comment: @IrkenInvader The chart at that link is key codes, whereas charCodeAt returns UTF-16 character codes. For the purposes of this, an ASCII table would be the relevant one.

Comment: My real question is, is this cipher stuff important?  I don't really see why'd I'd ever actually need to do this.  I'm more trying to get comfortable with knowing what each method does, and how I can use it if I so choose.

Comment: You won't need to write actual caesar ciphers day to day at a job, I imagine the exercise was just to practice using logic, functions, variables, and loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `charCode`, you get the unicode values of the characters, which are in the range 65–90 for the uppercase english alphabet. When you add 13, you get the unicode values for the characters "NOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefg", which is not what you want.

You need to find a way to only make english characters map to the the english character 13 steps away, and make this wrap around so that the later characters map to the earlier ones (so that Z maps to M).

This is probably easier to achieve if you drop using unicode values, instead using your own alphabet, like in the snippet below:

```js
function rot13(str) {
  let x = str.toUpperCase();
  let y = [];
  let n = "";
  let alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (alphabet.indexOf(x.charAt(i)) > -1) {
      n += alphabet.charAt((alphabet.indexOf(x.charAt(i)) + 13) % 26);
    } else {
      n += x.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  return n;
}

console.log(rot13("FREE PIZZA"));
```

An even simpler approach is to just use a lookup table (avoiding math altogether):

```js
function rot13(str) {
  let x = str.toUpperCase().split("");
  let table = {
    A: "N", B: "O", C: "P", D: "Q",
    E: "R", F: "S", G: "T", H: "U",
    I: "V", J: "W", K: "X", L: "Y",
    M: "Z", N: "A", O: "B", P: "C",
    Q: "D", R: "E", S: "F", T: "G",
    U: "H", V: "I", W: "J", X: "K",
    Y: "L", Z: "M"
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (table[x[i]]) {
      x[i] = table[x[i]];
    }
  }
  return x.join("");
}

console.log(rot13("FREE PIZZA"));
```

Comment: What exactly does %26 do?  Sry, self-learning, and there are a lot of gaps to fill in that Free Code Camp leaves out haha.

Comment: It is the [modulo operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()), it makes the character codes wrap around (late characters map to early ones).

Comment: Thanks, guess i'll have to maybe brush up my math skills a little earlier than planned haha!